# How to set space between words in MS Word

Tags: microsoft-word

When I am trying to `Justify` text paragraph in MS Word, random space is generating between words. How can I set `equal` gap between words and how can I change the setting of `Justify`

Answer (score 5):

You are probably justifying the text in Center mode, which means that the text must reach both ends of the page, left and right.

If the text-line is not exactly of the width of the printed page, the only way for Word to make both ends meet is by adding space in-between the words. Word in effect distributes the missing width pixels among the white-space in the line.

Word has a nice algorithm for this, and it's not at all random.

Answer (score 1):

Justify is meant to spread the text out over the width of the current container and shouldn't be used if you want equal widths between your words. To change the width of the space between the words you should change the font settings of the text: You can do this by selecting the text, do a right click and click Font, then go to the advanced tab where you can change the character spacing settings.

Comment: Enabling hyphenation will give Word more spacing options.

Answer (score 0):

Character Spacing in the Font dialog adjusts spacing between letters of the selected text. It barely adjusts the spacing between words. Word does not have a nice algorithm for spacing in my opinion. It is a lame attempt to emulate a publishing layout tool, which it is not. If you want to justify text and control the spacing to the 1/1000th of a em, use a professional layout application like Adobe InDesign. I never justify paragraph text in Word. It creates unsightly [rivers](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/River_%28typography%29) (uneven white space between words that flows down the page).

To increase the spacing between words, say in a title that is ALL CAPS, use two spaces. And if that creates too large a gap, reduce the font size of the spaces only. If you're thinking you could just increase the font size of a single space, then you'll discover this also affects the vertical line spacing (unless you've specified an exact line height).

Answer (score 0):

Found no way to get rid of that ugly spaces. All I could do is to select the gapped text with some more lines below it, then cut and paste using the option text only. that worked for me.

Comment: You've responded to a question that was posted 10 years ago. Answers that others have provided are also more appropriate. Please consider deleting your response.